# browser is not showing html tags in inspect element

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code. I don't know what's wrong with it, but the browser does not show the table in the inspector.

```
<main class="container clear">

  <?php

  require 'connect.inc.php';

  $query = "SELECT * FROM `names`";
  $name = mysql_query($query);
  $namelist = mysql_fetch_assoc($name);
  ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $namelist['name']; ?></td> 

    <td><?php echo $namelist['designation']; ?></td> 

    <td><?php echo $namelist['phone']; ?></td>

    <td><?php echo $namelist['email']; ?></td>

  </tr>

</main>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You do realize you have no table tags, right?

Comment: yes exactly this is what i m getting no table tags @JohnConde

Comment: help me out buddy @JohnConde

Comment: Um, maybe add the table tags to your code maybe? *sigh*

Comment: @John It's so crazy it just might work.

Comment: you mean inside php echo?? @JohnConde

Comment: that is also not working @JohnConde

Comment: Put an actual `<table>` tag right after your `<main>` tag, and close it with `</table>` right before `</main>`. The table tags will not appear without your help. Just type them right in there; don't `echo` them with PHP.

Comment: using this it is working.. but whats the error in using echo @Don'tPanic

Comment: Can you show us the rendered page please ?

Comment: @KaranPratapSingh I didn't mean that it was an _error_ to use `echo`, I just meant that it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't show a table because you are missing the `<table>` tag.

You'd do it like this:

```
    .. code ..
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            .. code ..
        </tr>
    </table>
</main>
```

---

Since you have a a query like `SELECT * FROM names`, I assume you want to show all the values, so your code should look like this:

```
<?php
require 'connect.inc.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `names`";
$name = mysql_query($query);
?>

<main class="container clear">
    <table border="1"> <!-- border just for you to see it -->
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while($namelist = mysql_fetch_assoc($name);
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $namelist['name'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $namelist['designation'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $namelist['phone'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $namelist['email'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</main>
```

---

**Side notes:**

- That table name is probably not the best option, specially for the fields (`name`, `designation`, `phone`, `email`) it has. Try using a name that is more suggestive.
- Oh.. and please, [stop using `mysql_*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) functions. This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.

Comment: Ok. I think I've done enough for now...

Comment: I agree use PDO !!!